# Haskell variant of template metaprogramming

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm new to Haskell. Given the whole premise of Haskell is that a function will always return the same value, I'd expect there to be some way of e.g. calculating fibonacci values of constants at compile time, like I can do in C++ with template metaprogrmming, but I can't see how to do it. Is there a way?

Comment: [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell), perhaps? It's even slightly less awful than template metaprogramming in C++, though that isn't saying much. Neither is much fun. :P

Comment: @C.A.McCann Does it work for fibs though?  My understanding was that TH was more like C macros, but that could be completely wrong.  (That said, template C++ is kind of just glorified macros, and hmm I guess it might be possible to define fibs in C at compile time just via macros, not sure...)  Anyway, concrete example would help.

Comment: TH is arbitrary Haskell code, executed at compile time, that can generate syntax trees to splice definitions, expressions, or whatever else into the code. C macros don't even begin to compare. It's nowhere near as limited as C++ template junk is, it's just kind of a pain to use for anything non-trivial because working with the AST data types is clumsy.

Comment: I've found it's very similar to how Lisp macros would feel if Lisp had actual syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

edit: Daniel Fischer points out that you can lift an ordinary expression into Template Haskell and evaluate the result at compile-time, subject to certain constraints on the output type, by having an ordinary function `fib` and then splicing

```
$(let x = fib 1000 in [|x|])
```

Original answer follows.

As pointed out in comments, Template Haskell is the way to go for this.  For inductive functions like fibonacci, it's fairly straightforward.  You write code similar to a standard definition, but returning an ExpQ value.  Due to splicing restrictions, you'll need to use 2 modules.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-} 
module TH where

import Language.Haskell.TH

fibTH :: Int -> ExpQ
fibTH 0 = [| 0 |]
fibTH 1 = [| 1 |]
fibTH n = [| $(fibTH (n-1)) + $(fibTH (n-2)) |]
```

and

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Main where

import TH

y :: Int
y = $(fibTH 10)

main = print y
```

To confirm that the work is performed at compile-time, we can compile with `-ddump-simpl` to see the core, which confirms it.

```
Main.y :: GHC.Types.Int
[GblId,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType m,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, WorkFree=False, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 10 20}]
Main.y = GHC.Types.I# 55
```

Comment: Isn't it much better to have an ordinary decent `fib` function in the other module and then splice `y = $(let x = fib 1000 in [|x|])`?

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't think to try that, it is better.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [great article](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/evolving-faster-haskell-programs-now-with-llvm/) by Don Stewart where he shows that using the LLVM backend with the right choice of flags will precompute certain functions at compile time and replace them with constants.

Comment: Well, kind of, but it seems rather trial-and-error (albeit organizedly-so) rather than directly deterministic.  C++ templates are more the latter; WYSIWYG, and I was hoping for more of that kind of solution.

Comment: @lobsterism Then you want Template Haskell.  I only mentioned this solution because you were asking about why we can't take advantage the purity of functions to pre-compile them.  However, Template Haskell does not take advantage of purity at all and it can even have side effects.